# How to add tomcat virtual hosts instances programatically

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, grails, apache2

I was working for the last 2 years on building a social network for companies using Grails.

A new requirement appeared which is creating separate virtual host for each company that will have it's own database of users, timelines, etc (I would like to avoid rewriting all the service layer)

So initially the application was running on http://www.my-social-network.com for example 
Now using an admin console that we will have to develop, companies should be able to create their own subdomain like this : http://company1.my-social-network.com and so on.

The web server that we are using is Apache 2.2  + tomcat 6

Is there someone who has an idea about how to do it?

Ideally I want to have one instance of the application that receives requests with different host names so it can behave differently in order to save resources because Grails consumes too much memory.
For example :

subdomain1.my-social-network.com --> apache 2 --> my-social-network.com (+ specific headers) --> tomcat

If such thing was possible, is there a way to select a datasource depending on a request parameter or header?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you want to have a webapp per different virtual host or would it be the same webapp which routes the traffic and sets some virtual host variable in the context?

Comment: I don't know I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different options you can take, but first you need to make a decision on how you are going to implement this at the lowest level:

1. You can take the requests to subdomain1.my-social-network.com and [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) the user to my-social-network.com.
2. Same as above but use [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), [HTTP 303](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) or [HTTP 307](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_307) instead.
3. Simply show the contents of the site, responding with [HTTP 200](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_200) (probably the best approach as these domains are meant to be permanent). Further text assumes this option.

Next, you need to have a [servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which intercepts all HTTP traffic and has a map `{virtual_path -> real_site}`. This filter can simply set relevant [request attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) (hint: `servletRequest.setAttribute(String, Object)`)  when it detects that requested virtual path is recognized.

If a user creates/renames/deletes a domain/virtual path, you would populate the map accordingly.

Finally, your render component should check that parameter and render relevant site. It is really hard to elaborate further without knowing more details on how your application works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to redirect the user to another url but I want him to keep working on the original URL. Is there a way to do that between tomcat and apache?

Comment: Sure, this is option 3). Have you tried setting up servlet filter like I described?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the option 3 very much. Are you saying that we should (apache side) all subdomains to tomcat and add a http request parameter that will be consumed by the application's business logic ?
If so how to do such thing with apache? which modules to use? etc

Comment: My point is that you should be handling all of this in Tomcat, not Apache. Apache should just forward all domains to your Tomcat where the decision which site to show is done.

Comment: Handling all this in tomcat means doing that we should do it in the business logic right? I'd like to make it better way and that's why I'm posting this question here. Usually how is it done? Many people do it and I don't think it's very complicated

Comment: We do it exactly the way I have explained. This allows us to add/remove any virtual paths in the runtime.